# PHP Script for Downloading more than 2GB Image ZIP

Tags: php, apache

On the Server I created Zip file for images..Size of zip is more than 2 GB. I want to download zip file.. Some times file downloading stops or fails when using below script. I had change server variables..

```
if (!$filename) {
    // if variable $filename is NULL or false display the message
    echo $err;
} else {
    // define the path to your download folder plus assign the file name
    $ordercode = $_GET['ordercode'];
    $refId = $_GET['refId'];        

    $path = 'files/'.$refId.'/'.$ordercode.'/'.$filename;

    // check that file exists and is readable
    if (file_exists($path) && is_readable($path)) {
        // get the file size and send the http headers
        $size = filesize($path);
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Length: '.$size);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

        // open the file in binary read-only mode
        // display the error messages if the file can´t be opened
        $file = @ fopen($path, 'rb');
        if ($file) {
            // stream the file and exit the script when complete
            fpassthru($file);
            exit;
        } else {
            echo $err;
        }
    } else {
        echo $err;
    }
}
```

Comment: **Be aware that clients can download whatever file your server can read!** You should tell what "stop" and "fail" mean in your question. It's not good practice to suppress errors, like in @fopen.

Answer (score 0):

Try it by writing below two lines above your code:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 10000);//you can change this value
ini_set("memory_limit", "6400M");//you can change this value
```

Comment: I already Added below varaibles.. ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '5000M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 100000);